# what to call a person who can easily hit a younger one without any sorrow?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-usage

Please, help me find the word that describes a person (in my case a man) that can punch a much younger adult (in my case a 20 year old boy) without any sorrow about it.

Comment: I don't know a specific term, but such a man is an asshole. Pardon my French.

Comment: Bully, coward, assailant, ...

Comment: Would it be "a thug"?

Comment: No single word suffices, but *bully* comes close.

Answer (score 2):

You could say that person is a bully.

> **bully**
>
> a person who uses strength or influence to harm or intimidate those who are weaker.

Another alternative, the word **thug**, has some criminal connotation and therefore may not convey exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

If the intention is to convey that the older person derives pleasure from punching another person, maybe the term 'sadist' will work.

> Sadist is the term for individuals who derive pleasure from the suffering of others

Comment: Hello, Arora. I've seen some low quality posts' review results where you chose "Looks OK" for bad answers. Please review more carefully, or we will end up with bad answers all over the site. Let us together keep the site in good quality. :)